# can we sent a single email for items created in document library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

Currently in a sharepoint designer workflow when an item is created it send email fro all the items. for example if 10 files are uploaded it will fire 10 emails. is there any chance to sent 1 email with compiled report for all the files uploaded ?

Comment: Can you please let me know is there a single user/Admin only going to add the documents or many users?

Comment: there are many users

Comment: If 10 users added 20 document then how many email you are expecting per user?

Comment: 10 emails. its is based on uploads not documents. if i set alerts it will send emails for eah and every items added. inbox will be filled with mails like spam

Comment: Do you have fixed iterations for the user like if A user will add 5 items once started adding documnet to library?
then only you can add the condition otherwise there might not be real time solution.

Comment: Sorry this may be not an exact solution. But in this case we are using SharePoint  alerts where we get a daily summary of all files uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

For SharePoint On-Premise you can use a Timer Job for this use case
For SharePoint Online you can use a CSOM console app and schedule it using scheduler.

For workflows, you can go for Site Workflow in this case.

Comment: Currently i am using sharepoint designer workflow. with just one action to sent emails and the workflow gets initiated upon item creation, which leads to a lot of emails . How does a Site workflow helps sort out this problem in document library ?

Comment: A site workflow can be scheduled. so it doesnt work on a list action. Hence you can schedule the site workflow to check the list for any new updates.. and then fetch all these information and send it as an email

Comment: @dsouzajoel22 Is it possible if multiple users have added the Documents then how it will work? Either it will send email to all users or only owner who added document, what? Can you please elaborate it more?

Comment: which is why for such complex conditions... site workflow may not be the right solution. It can work for simple logic... For more complex logic i suggest you go for CSOM console app and schedule it

Comment: yes we can do that or add an alert and schedule it daily or weekly. But my requirement is to sent an email will compiled details of all the files uploaded as soon as the files are uploaded,

Comment: i have created windows application for CSOM as test . How will add a console app to the office 365 environment.?

Comment: You cannot add this to Office 365 environment. This is to be hosted on a server or system... Could be Azure or a Local System

Comment: can you give me some reference for me to take a look at it.? Azure will be better. and it would be helpful to know a starting point for CSOM work flows.

Comment: https://sandervandevelde.wordpress.com/2016/07/19/turning-a-console-app-into-a-long-running-azure-webjob/